# Is Quotient Spaces of Hausdorff also Hausdorff where the Quotient Spaces is T1?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

Let X be Hausdorff space and X/~ be "~ Quotient Spaces",

Given that X/~ is T1,

Does it satisfy for X/~ to be Hausdorff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be two copies of the real line, and let $X\to Y$ be the quotient map that identifies the two lines along the set $\{x\neq 0\}$.

$X$ is Hausdorff, but $Y$, the "line with doubled origin", is locally Hausdorff and therefore $T_1$, but not Hausdorff.

---

In fact, *every* topological space is the quotient of a Hausdorff space.  This appears to have been proved by [M. Shimrat in 1956](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/7/1/128.extract), though there may be a very short argument.

I think that something stronger should be true: every topological space $Y$ is a quotient of a *Stonean space*, which is a Hausdorff [extremally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) space.  I believe that it is possible to show this by embedding the complete lattice of opens in $Y$ into a complete Boolean algebra, though if $Y$ is not sober this may complicate the proof or weaken the conclusion.

Comment: @CameronBuie Ah, I seem to have forgotten that rather crucial observation.

Comment: I've been there!

Comment: thanks, can i ask what gave you the motivation for this example?

Comment: @MatanL I first picked the standard $T_1$ example of the cofinite topology on an infinite set, but I could not quickly determine if it was the quotient of a Hausdorff space.  So I tried picking a space with stronger properties, and the line with doubled origin is the standard example of a non-Hausdorff locally Hausdorff space—and it is quickly intuitive that it is a quotient of a Hausdorff space.  I recently asked [a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555587/general-facts-about-locally-hausdorff-spaces) about locally Hausdorff spaces, so they've been on my mind.

Comment: again, thanks :)

Comment: @MatanL Sure thing. :)  I just added some musings; it seems to be the case that every topological space is a quotient of a Hausdorff space, though perhaps not trivially so.

Comment: There is a very short argument that every $T_1$ space is a quotient of an extremally disconnected Hausdorff space using convergence of ultrafilters (namely, $X$ is the quotient of the disjoint union of copies of spaces with the same underlying set as $X$, one witnessing each nonprincipal ultrafilter which converges in $X$).  With a slight modification to handle principal ultrafilters, it can be adapted to non-$T_1$ spaces as well.