# Is a continuous image of a normal space normal?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

> *Problem* Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be closed continuous surjective map. Show that if $X$ is normal then So is $Y$.

What if we drop the 'closed' condition? I want a counter example. I know the proof of this theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be $\Bbb N$ with the discrete topology, let $Y$ be $\Bbb N$ with the cofinite topology, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity map. Clearly $X$ is normal and $f$ is continuous and surjective. However, $Y$ is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff, so it clearly is not normal.

Comment: Can you explain  $\Bbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology? Please.

Comment: @Joseph: If $X$ is any set, the cofinite topology on $X$ is $$\{\varnothing\}\cup\{X\setminus F:F\text{ is finite}\}\;.$$ That is, the open sets are the empty set and the sets whose complements are finite. Equivalently, the closed sets are $X$ and the finite sets.

Comment: $\Bbb{N}$ with cofinite topology ,$\Bbb{N}$  is only closed set.

Comment: @Joseph: No, all of the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ are also closed.

Comment: Ahh yes. How can I comment(previous comment) like that? Thanks a lot Professor.

Comment: @Joseph: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f\colon \Bbb R\amalg\Bbb R\to \Bbb R\amalg\Bbb R/\sim$, where $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$ for all $x\neq 0$. That is, $f$ is the quotient map to the line with a doubled-origin. Clearly $f$ is continuous and surjective (as are all quotient maps), but $f$ is not closed: take an interval $[0,1]$ in the first copy of $\Bbb R$. Then $f([0,1])$ is the interval $(0,1]$ plus one of the two origin points. This set is not closed since the preimage consists of $[0,1]$ in the first copy of $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1]$ in the second copy.

Comment: But why is the quotient space here non normal?

Comment: The two origins can't be covered with disjoint open sets

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ be *any* topological space and let $X$ be $Y$ with the discrete topology.  Then $X$ is normal, and the identity map $X\to Y$ is a continuous surjection.  So, any non-normal space $Y$ at all will give a counterexample in this way.

(In fact, more strongly, every topological space is a *quotient* of a normal space.  See for instance the construction in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682677/86856).)