# Quotient of completely regular space that is not completely regular

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

What are some examples of a topological space $X$ that is completely regular $T_0$ (hence Hausdorff) having a quotient space $Y = X/\sim$ that is *not* completely regular? Preferably such examples where $Y$ is not even regular.

Here I take "completely regular" to mean simply that each closed subset and each point not in such a subset can be separated by a numerical function; and likewise "regular" to mean that each closed subset and each point not in such a subset can be separated by neighborhoods. That is, I do *not* include the property of being $T_0$ as part of either definition — so that a quotient that merely fails to be $T_0$ without failing to have this separation property is *not* what I'm asking about,

Comment: *Every* space is a quotient of a normal $T_1$ space; see my construction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682677/86856) for instance.

Comment: @EricWofsey: some examples that are more specific and concrete, where one starts with a completely regular $T_0$-space and forms a quotient of it that is not completely regular but is $T_0$ or even $T_1$? The only one I know off-hand is the quotient of the real line obtained by collapsing the set of rationals to a point.