# Example of nonnormal completely regular $T_{0}$ space that is quotient of normal $T_{1}$ space.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I'm seeking "best possible" examples of a nonnormal quotient of a normal space, namely, a nonnormal but completely regular $T_{0}$ space $Y$ that is the quotient of a normal $T_{1}$-space $X$.

The more "concrete" and "geometric" the better!

Are there any such examples other than those constructed by the method from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682677/32337 (which uses ultrafilters) or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1569463/32337 (which uses cardinality)?

Examples that avoid both cardinality and ultrafilters  would be desireable.possible.

*Related:* [Examples of a quotient of a normal topological space that is not normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107266/examples-of-a-quotient-of-a-normal-topological-space-that-is-not-normal). Note that the quotient spaces in the accepted answer there are either not regular or not Hausdorff, so do not constitute a "best posssible" example.

Answer (score 2):

It was shown by Hanai that a $T_1$ space is first-countable if and only if it is an open image of a metric space. See

> S. Hanai, *Open Mappings II*, Proc. Japan Acad. **37**, (1961),  233-238.

I believe the result is also often credited to Ponomarev.

Since every open surjection is quotient, to answer your question will suffice to find any first-countable, completely regular, $T_1$ space which is not normal. The [Niemytzki plane](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000074) works.

This particular example can be made explicit by noticing that the Niemytzki plane $N$ is locally metrisable. Thus let $\mathcal{U}$ be any open cover of $N$ by metrisable open sets and let $X=\bigsqcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}} U$ be the disjoint union of the members of $\mathcal{U}$. The obvious mappings $\pi:X\rightarrow N$ is a continuous open surjection of a metrisable space onto a non-normal space.

Comment: I don't see why a basic open neighborhood $N = \{(x, 0)\} \cup B_{r}((x, 0))$ of a point $(x, 0)$ on the horizontal is metrizable. In particular, for such a metric, inducing the relative topology on $N$ from the Niemytzki plane, what would be the distance between $(x, 0)$ and other points in $N$?

Comment: Murray, every second-countable regular Hausdorff space is metrisable by the Urysohn Metrisation Theorem. Clearly this applies to $N$ (choose a countable neighbourhood base at each point of $B$ with rational coordinates and add to these a countable neighbourhood base for the point $(x,0)$. The resulting collection is a countable base for $N$). Of course its fairly easy to see what a compatible metric might look like...

Comment: Invoking the Urysohn Metrization Theorem seems to be hitting a small nail with a sledgehammer. How about a direct way?

Comment: I think you saw in your other question that there is no trick. Do you still need a pointer?

Comment: Please seem my 2nd comment (the 3rd comment in all) to the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4412135/32337. I'm just not seeing something.

Comment: I anxiously await seeing a compatible metric on a basic neighborhood $N$ of $(x, 0)$ in the Niemytzki plane $\Gamma$.